# How do I disable a module when Drush or the GUI doesnt work?

Tags: 7, rules, drush, wsod

My site just gives a WSOD and throws this error:

> Error: Unsupported operand types in sites/all/modules/rules/includes/rules.state.inc, line 620

Since I can't even get to my site now without a WSOD, and when I do a `rush cc all` or `drush pm-disable rules` I get that error via the command line, how can I disable the Rules module?

Answer (score 11):

If you have access to your database, you can do it through there.

You can see all the modules enabled with:

```
SELECT name,status FROM system WHERE type='module' AND status='1';
```

You can disable a module by setting it's status to 0.

```
UPDATE system SET status='0' WHERE name='module_name';
```

[For more on uninstalling stuff via drupal's db.](https://www.drupal.org/node/157632)

Comment: How would you set the site as maintenance mode aswell via the db?  thanks!

Comment: UPDATE variable SET value = 's:1:"0";' WHERE name= 'maintenance_mode';

Comment: There is a chance that you may need to clear the cache table using DELETE FROM cache WHERE cid = 'variables'; if the site doesn't recognize it's in maintenance mode. Not sure if that would be the case for you or not because of your errors.